# User has to press button multiple times to react

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a few buttons and sometimes, I have to push them multiple times to get the button to work. It highlights the button as if it is a hover effect, then the next time it goes through. This seems to only happen on mobile. I'm using bootstrap too.

Here is the code:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list" style="list-style-type: none;padding:0; margin:0;">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">
    <div style="width:100%;height: 43px;">
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"> Item1 </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4"> $1 </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="padding:0px">
          <button class="wish-small-button" ng-click="deleteItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
          <button class="wish-small-button" ng-click="editItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
       </div>
    </div>
 </li>
```

```
.wish-small-button {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.item {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
   position: relative;
   font-weight: 300;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   color: #00E676;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 18px;
   padding:5px;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10657

Seems that bootstrap buttons do not play nice in mobile.

I switched to anchor tags like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
   <a class="item-small-button" ng-click="deleteItem(item)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
</div>
```